# Retrieve SubString Auto Hot Key

Tags: parsing, macros, substring, autohotkey

I have a list of strings I am trying to loop through within AutoHotkey, but within each loop I need to split each value into separate button presses:

```
 List := ["1111","1222","1498"]
 for key, value in List
      Send, SubStr(val,1,1)
      Send, SubStr(val,2,1)
      Send, SubStr(val,3,1)
      Send, SubStr(val,4,1)
```

The send isn't working and I suspect it is because my Send, SubStr code isn't written correctly. I would appreciate any advice/expertise thank you :)

Comment: Which language you are using, Python?

Comment: @GursewakSingh It's AutoHotkey.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but I'm guessing it might be because of legacy syntax. You should use [expressions](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm#-expression) instead.

```
List := ["1111","1222","1498"]
for key, val in List
     Send % SubStr(val,1,1)
     Send % SubStr(val,2,1)
     Send % SubStr(val,3,1)
     Send % SubStr(val,4,1)
```

Comment: Good answer! Also, note the mismatch between "value" and "val"; otherwise, it works.

Comment: @EJE Thanks, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score -1):

check for loop parse csv in autohotkey help